# Change background color for lightning:tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

How can I set background color for selected tab in lightning:tabset

```
<lightning:tabset>
    <lightning:tab label="Item One">
        Sample Content One
    </lightning:tab>
    <lightning:tab label="Item Two">
        Sample Content Two
    </lightning:tab>
</lightning:tabset>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Tab or the tab detail?

Comment: tab itself not the detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following CSS in your component

```
.THIS slds-tabs--default__nav li.slds-active{
     background: red;
}
```

Adjust as needed

Answer (score 1):

Try Add this following In **css**

```
.THIS .slds-tabs--default__item.slds-active{
     background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the CSS below worked for me:

```
.THIS .slds-tabs_default__item.slds-is-active {
    background: greenyellow !important;
}
```