# How to apply different color for each lightning tab in Lightning tabset?

Tags: lightning

Can we apply different colors for the above two Lightning tabs
?? My requirement is to apply Red color for "Item One" and Green for "Item Two". Please help me how to do.

```
<lightning:tabset>
<lightning:tab label="Item One">
    Sample Content One 
</lightning:tab>
<lightning:tab label="Item Two">
    Sample Content Two
</lightning:tab>
```

Answer (score 0):

See link below about similar issue.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/161212/77268

Answer From Link:

```
.THIS slds-tabs--default__nav li.slds-active{
     background: red;
}
```